# Trying to understand INDEX; MATCH; MAX

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm still a beginner with Excel. Would like some help with the following example.
[image: Example]

Formula will be in B9 & C9.
I want the last value to be shown according to the Numbers and Letters in B9 and then the corresponding date were the value was found in C9

Basically I want to find out what was the last value from "Four" for "A". There are multiple "A" inserts. The formula I used returns the value 0, which is true as you can see in cell H9. But I need the formula to realize that there is no value in that cell and show the previous cell with value, that will be F9 that contains "500"

The formula I used is:

```
=INDEX($F$6:$I$9, MATCH($A9,$E$6:$E$9,0), MATCH(MAX(INDEX(($F$5:$I$5=$B$4)*$F$4:$I$4,)), $F$4:$I$4, 0))
```

How can I get it to return the the last non-blank value from a row where the same column in another row is a specific value?

Comment: Looks like Toast and I have two slightly different approaches. In my solution I assume the date columns are sorted chronologically and so I gather up all "A" columns then pick the last one that isn't zero. The date row can be anything/text and is just an additional lookup that carries with the MATCH & FILTER. Toast filters all non-zero "A" columns and selects the latest date from the date row. This is quite neat as the dates can be in any order, but requires the dates to be date numbers and not text. Also, other than LET which isn't required, doesn't need Excel 365 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I hope you have Office 365!**

```
=LET(x, FILTER(F9:I9,(F$5:I$5="A")*(F9:I9) <> 0,""), INDEX(x, COLUMNS(x)))
```

**Explanation:**

(F5:I5="A")*(F9:I9) gives the whole row FOUR, but zero'ed in columns that doesn't contain an "A".

Next we FILTER the above for all non-zero columns. The last item in this filtered array is the value you want. To get to the last item, we use LET to "save" the whole array as x, then COLUMNS(x) is the index to the last item and INDEX(x, COLUMNS(x)) returns said item.

**Expansion to get to the date**

```
=LET(x, FILTER(F4:Z9,(F5:Z5="A")*(F9:Z9) <> 0,""), INDEX(x, 1, COLUMNS(x)))
```

Basically we expanded the FILTER array to include from row 4, which will now return a 2D array. INDEX into row 1 to get to the date.

**Boss version**

```
=LET(x, FILTER(F4:Z9,(F5:Z5="A")*(F9:Z9) <> 0,""), INDEX(x, {6,1}, COLUMNS(x)))
```

The boss version is very efficient and returns both the value and the date as a single array.

**Expand even further to include looking up column A**

```
=LET(y, MATCH(A9,E6:E9,0), x, FILTER(F4:K9,((F5:K5="A")*INDEX(F4:K9,y+2,)) <> 0,""), INDEX(x, y+2, COLUMNS(x)))
```

and for the date

```
=LET(y, MATCH(A9,E6:E9,0), x, FILTER(F4:K9,((F5:K5="A")*INDEX(F4:K9,y+2,)) <> 0,""), INDEX(x, 1, COLUMNS(x)))
```

Unfortunately, there is no "boss" version of this, as {y+1, 1} isn't a static array. Arrays in Excel must contain only constants.

Comment: Thank you Mobus,

Comment: @Wim no problem = interesting problem. I was wondering if there is a non-FILTER way to do this for non office 365 users. Basically, comes down to how to find the last non-zero item in an array. Thereafter getting to the date from there might be super challenging. Could use helper rows, but urgh.

Comment: Oh and please do checkmark the solution so others may know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Sorry Mobus,

I do have Office 365. I still struggle to get it working.

I obviously did not explain my workbook very well. Table 1 is on sheet 1 and the second table is on sheet 2. On both tables I filter by alphabet or by color codes. This must not influence the answer for the above formula. So it is important that text in Column A = Column E(different sheet) match when calculating the row. Can I put in something like:

=LET(x, FILTER(MATCH(A9, E6:E9, 0), (F5:I5=$B$4)*MATCH(A9, E6:E9, 0) <> 0, " "), INDEX(x, COLUMNS(x)))

It does not work. Hope you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Right so the way I wrote the formula was obviously just for the example table and requires for row "FOUR" in the A:B table to be on the same row as the E:I table. Things do get a little more complicated if you have to find the row first... I'll try and update the solution.

Comment: Thanks Mobus, struggle to get it to work with my workbook. I agree with you that Toast has a neat approach, but also can't get it to work with my workbook. Character limits? Workbook stretches till DD263. Bosco's formula works just fine. I'll keep testing all options. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I got your formula to work very well! My count should have been y+4 in my actual workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `LET()` function to define variable names so it was easier for me to follow what was happening.

```
=LET(dateRow,$F$4:$I$4,letter,B$4,letterRow,$F$5:$I$5,number,$A6,numberColumn,$E$6:$E$9,dataRow,OFFSET(letterRow,MATCH(number,numberColumn,0),0),dataColumn,MATCH(MAX(dateRow*(letterRow=letter)*(dataRow<>0))&letter,dateRow&letterRow,0),IFERROR(INDEX(dataRow,1,dataColumn),""))
```

I know that looks huge but it breaks down easily. First, we define several variables so we can reference them by name later. You don't have to do this and can directly reference the ranges in later parts of the formula, but it helps me follow what's happening.

```
dateRow,$F$4:$I$4
letter,B$4
letterRow,$F$5:$I$5
number,$A6
numberColumn,$E$6:$E$9
```

Next, we'll find which row in the data has the right number (One, Two, Three, Four) in the first column.

`dataRow,OFFSET(letterRow,MATCH(number,numberColumn,0),0)`

Then we need column we want. This is a little meatier and it's where your current formula isn't' working for you. The key here is to just add more criteria inside the `MAX()` function.
`dateRow*(letterRow=letter)*(dataRow<>0)`
is equivalent to
`IF(AND(letterRow=letter,dataRow<>0),dateRow,0)`.

With that understanding, we can look at a shorter version of this part:
`dataColumn,MATCH(MAX(~)&letter,dateRow&letterRow,0)`

We concatenate `letter` and `letterRow` so that we find the right column in the event that a date appears more than once with different letters underneath it. Now that we know what row the data is in (`dataRow`) and what column (`dataColumn`), we can pull the value we want:
`IFERROR(INDEX(dataRow,1,dataColumn),"")`

We wrapped it inside `IFERROR()` to cover when a value isn't found. For instance, If you want the value for TWO-A, it would return an error because there aren't any non-blank values for TWO-A.

For the Date formula in column `C`, it is identical except for one letter because we want to pull the value from the `dateRow` instead of the `dataRow`:

```
=LET(dateRow,$F$4:$I$4,letter,B$4,letterRow,$F$5:$I$5,number,$A6,numberColumn,$E$6:$E$9,dataRow,OFFSET(letterRow,MATCH(number,numberColumn,0),0),dataColumn,MATCH(MAX(dateRow*(letterRow=letter)*(dataRow<>0))&letter,dateRow&letterRow,0),IFERROR(INDEX(datRow,1,dataColumn),""))
```

Comment: Hi Toast, yes it does looks huge. But yet simple. It works very well on my example, but for some reason it does not work on my actual workbook. Could there be a character limit? Workbook stretches till DD263.

Comment: I don't think anything in the formula would care about a big range although it is important that `dateRow` and `letterRow` have the same number of columns. What happens when it doesn't work? Does it return an error or an unexpected value?

Answer (score 0):

1] In "Last Value" `B6`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(1/LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX($F$6:$I$9,MATCH($A6,$E$6:$E$9,0),0)/($F$5:$I$5=$B$4)),"")
```

2] In "Date" `C6`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,$F$4:$I$4/(INDEX($F$6:$I$9,MATCH($A6,$E$6:$E$9,0),0)<>"")/($F$5:$I$5=$B$4)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bosco, short but strong. Works a charm!

Comment: Ingenious way to use divide by zero errors inside iferror to filter the data. Note though this formula might give trouble if your table numbers are smaller than 1.

Comment: @Mobus, Thanks, post edited in change from ">0" into "<>"" ".